# Dayjs to JS Date for Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dayjs

I need to parse a user supplied date in NodeJS. I found answers stating that using built in Date constructor/parse method is not reliable and I should use some library like Moment. I was confused that there are Moment and MomentJS libraries and found that there is a tiny library DaysJS having the same interface. Parsing works fine but I cannot find a way how to get the JS Date object that I need to pass to Mongo. Is there any aother way than extract the unix milliseconds and pass it to Date constructor?

When I pass daysjs instance to Mongo NodeJS driver, it fails:

```
const day = dayjs('2020-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
2020-06-07 10:42:33:093 [error]: Request failedThe dollar ($) prefixed field '$L' in 'info.date.$L' is not valid for storage.
```

This seems to work:

```
let publishDate = new Date(1000 * dayjs().unix());
```

Is it the correct way of daysjs with Mongo?

Comment: Have you tried `dayjs('2020-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD').toDate()` ?

Comment: I was searching for it. Probably I am blind.

Comment: @thammada.ts I think you should consider posting that as an answer instead of a comment. It'll probably be accepted too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you got is because you tried to pass a `DayJS` object to mongodb, which it doesn't support.

You can pass a javascript `Date` object to mongodb. In order to convert a `DayJS` object to plain javascript `Date` object you can use `.toDate()` on the `DayJS` object

```
dayjs('2020-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD').toDate()
```